# Postpone SSG to first request

Tags: next.js

I have some pages that could benefit from being statically generated by implementing `getStaticProps`. The problem is, inside `getStaticProps` I need to call some api and access resources aren't available when I want to do the build (that is when building the docker container in which next.js will run).

Is there a way to tell next.js that I want to postpone the build of some pages untill they are requested for the first time? I feel like it should be possible, the `revalidate` option for `getStaticProps` *almost* does what I want (it re-generates the page the first time it's called if the previously generated one is older that X), problem is, it still tries to generate the page on `next build`.

There's also the `fallback` option for `getStaticPaths` that *almost* works for me because it allows to postpone the generation of a *dynamic-route* page. Problem is, I need it for *static-route* pages too.

Comment: Why this api and resources are unavailable? If you are trying to fetch from same app api route then it is not encouraged to do, you should refactor your code and use handlers directly in `getStaticProps`. Last note inside that section https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

Comment: I've yet to decide if I will implement api directly in next.js or in another container, but the problem is similar, the whole solution will use 5 or 6 containers (including the database), and most of them will need to be running for the api to fully work. I'd like the build process to be as independent as possibile, whatever page depends on something else should be build (just one time) at runtime

Comment: You'll need to make sure the API is ready before you can build the Next.js app properly, I don't think there's a way around that.

Comment: Can't you cheat by using a dynamic route, but expect only one parameter (your actual static route name) to be the right one and trigger a 404 if it's not the right parameter? Hackish but that would do the job. You may definitely want to open a feature request or a discussion on Next github, this is an interesting edge case.

Comment: @EricBurel yea I thought about that possible hack, tried it and it worked, but I don't want to base my design on that. Another hack I've found is try-catching getStaticProps and setting a revalidate value of 1 if it fails, and a bigger value when it works, the only problem is that the request that cause the re-build will still get the old version, so I would need a script that fetches all my static pages when starting the container

Comment: Added a link to your question to a somewhat related thread I've opened about more advanced static generation patterns: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17631